# PHP inside a JQuery function issue

Tags: php, jquery

I'm trying to add the php code below to the `value=""` attribute inside the jquery function but when I run the html code the PHP code itself is displayed I was wondering how can I fix this problem so the PHP code itself is not displayed?

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var max_fields = 2;
    var x = 1;

    $('.add').click(function(e){
        //e.preventDefault();
        e.preventDefault();
        //stop the click from bubbling
        e.stopPropagation();    

        if(x < max_fields){ 
            x++;    
            $(this).closest('li').append('<div class="container"><input type="text" name="first_name[]" value="" /></label></div>');    
        }

});
```

PHP

```
<php if(!empty($_POST['first_name'])){ echo $first_name; } ?>
```

Comment: Does the file have a `.php` suffix? Are you accessing it through a server? PHP doesn't run when you access a local file, only a server.

Comment: the jquery gets called from a .php file

Comment: And are you accessing the .php file using a server?

Comment: The jquery comes out fine its the PHP part the does not.

Comment: The rest of my php code that is not in the jquery file works fine.

Comment: What do you mean by jquery file? Is the jquery in an external `.js` file that you load with `<script src="filename.js">`?

Comment: Yes its in external .js file

Comment: That won't work. PHP is only executed when it's in a `.php` file. Also, that file won't have access to variables from the original `.php` file -- every file has its own variables (except for session variables).

Comment: you can't use php tags inside js files. .php files process inside server. .js file process by browser

Comment: How can I make it work so that when extra fields are added by using Jquery I can load the values using PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to use PHP code in a `.js` file, but that won't work. PHP is normally only executed in `.php` files, and even if you configure your webserver to execute PHP in a `.js` file, it won't have acecss to the original script's `$_POST` variables.

What you can do is set a Javascript variable from the original `.php` file, and then use that in the `.js` file.

```
<script>
var first_name = <?php echo json_encode($_POST['first_name']); ?>;
</script>
<script src="filename.js"></script>
```

Then in `filename.js` you can use the `first_name` variable:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var max_fields = 2;
    var x = 1;

    $('.add').click(function(e){
        //e.preventDefault();
        e.preventDefault();
        //stop the click from bubbling
        e.stopPropagation();    

        if(x < max_fields){ 
            x++;    
            $(this).closest('li').append('<div class="container"><input type="text" name="first_name[]" value="' + first_name + '" /></label></div>');    
        }

});
```

Comment: Thanks I will give that a try. If I have any more issues I will ask another question again thanks for all the help.